# Use innosetup script to delete previously installed application folder

Tags: inno-setup

I am deleting the previous application using the script which inturn calls my .net app. All i want is to actually delete the folder(entire app1) from start menu (start->Programs->app1->uninstall app1)?

Thanks
Gauls

Answer (score 11):

If you just want to delete the "uninstall app1" icon from the Start menu, the following should work:

```
[InstallDelete]
Type: files; Name: "{group}\uninstall app1"
```

If you want to remove the entire program group from the start menu, use the following:

```
[InstallDelete]
Type: filesandordirs; Name: "{group}"
```

This assumes that your Inno Setup script Start menu folder name is the same as the previous "app1" application.

Comment: If you need to remove the particular menu item, you need to apply .lnk for example: Type: files; Name: "{group}\uninstall app1.lnk"

Answer (score 6):

None of those worked for me, after work-around, here is my solution;
in **[Setup]**

```
//Delete old entry folder from start menu
procedure DeleteOldStartMenuEntry;
var
 entry: String;
begin
 //Replace "Diviner" with desired folder name 
 entry := ExpandConstant('{commonprograms}') + '\Diviner\';
 if DirExists(entry) then begin
   DelTree(entry, true, true, true);
  end 
end;
```

Inside *InitializeSetup* call your procedure :

```
function InitializeSetup: Boolean;
var:
    ....
begin
    ....
    DeleteOldStartMenuEntry;
    ....
end;
```

Comment: This worked like a charm for me - InnoSetup even closes Explorer windows to be able to delete the directory.

Answer (score 2):

Thanks Craig my new app doesn't have the same name (app2) following worked for me

```
[InstallDelete]
Type: filesandordirs; Name: {commonprograms}\app1
```

Comment: Note that this won't work if the user has changed the default installation path.

Comment: Do you mean it won't work if the user has not installed under programfiles?