# Use Inno Setup to delete another application not installed with Inno Setup during installation

Tags: installshield, inno-setup, uninstallation

I have an old VB6 application that is deployed using a very old 16 bit version of InstallShield.  I have created a new installer with Inno Setup to be 64 bit friendly for my VB6 application with updates.

All of my users already have the existing InstallShield version installed.  Currently, I have Inno Setup working.  The problem is, I do not want to overwrite the old InstallShield installation files, so my Inno Setup installs to another directory.  This causes problems because now I have two versions installed, with two separate icons.

I need a way to invoke the uninstaller of the old InstallShield application when I install the new Inno Setup version.  How do I call the uninstaller from the Windows Add/remove programs through Inno Setup?  If i reuse the app id for the InstallShield version to be the same as the Inno Setup, and then manually delete the old files, would that work?

Comment: dunno if you figured it out but here is a good solution http://stackoverflow.com/a/2466537/541038

Answer (score 6):

You would have to locate the InstallShield uninstall registry key which will reside under either `HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE\SOFTWARE\Microsoft\Windows\CurrentVersion\Uninstall\` or `HKEY_CURRENT_USER\SOFTWARE\Microsoft\Windows\CurrentVersion\Uninstall\` and then execute its `UninstallString` value. Once that is done, delete the registry key: it is not possible to reuse the same key with Inno Setup since it will always append `_is1` to your `AppId` to generate the uninstall registry key name. Additionally on older Windows versions it may also truncate this key name and append a checksum, because of length limitations.

Do all this from a `PrepareToInstall` event function.